# Matching 2 columns in 2 separate data frames with different order, and returning yet another value

Tags: r, match, grepl

I have 2 dataframes where I am looking to match 2 columns of text data (I am familiar with using the match() function for matching dataframes using one column).

Dataframe A is a subset of dataframe B, but the data in the 2 columns might appear in the opposite order, ie Dog-Cat may be Cat-Dog. Dataframe B also contains an extra column of numeric values. I want to match dataframe A to dataframe B and then return the numeric column. There will be a match in all instances.

Dataframe A

```
Cat      Dog
Mouse    Cat
Rat      Cat
Rat      Dog
```

Dataframe B

```
Giraffe  Cat        0.7
Rat      Cat        0.2
Cat      Mouse      0.6
Cat      Dog        0.9
Giraffe  Elephant   0.1
Dog      Rat        0.3
```

The matched data should read

```
Cat      Dog         0.9
Mouse    Cat         0.6
Rat      Cat         0.2
Rat      Dog         0.3
```

I attempted with `match()` and with trying to concatenate the test strings. Also not sure if `grepl()` will help here.

Comment: Apologies again, but the data frames have not appeared as I typed them. To be clear, there are 2 columns in dataframe A and 3 in dataframe B

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do the merge normally, and with the columns swapped, and `rbind` the two results:

```
rbind( merge(A,B), merge(A,B, by.x=c('V1', 'V2'), by.y=c('V2', 'V1')))
     V1  V2  V3
1   Cat Dog 0.9
2   Rat Cat 0.2
3 Mouse Cat 0.6
4   Rat Dog 0.3
```